# scrapy: issues with saved data in csv file

Tags: python, web, scrapy

Today I scraped an unusual data in a website...
most of the links that I have scraped so far are great and directs me to the page
but this time, I encountered a data like this.

```
href="?fuseaction=search.jobDetails&template=dsp_job_details.cfm&cJobId=389139">
```

of course, I expect something like

```
http://example.com
```

which is a link...

Comment: What's your question? you can use `urlparse.urljoin()` to generate a full URL with `response.url` and the `href` value.
what are you using to follow links? CralwSpider? or are you generating Request() by extracting `href` values?

Comment: double yes. I am using crawlspider for it and I generate the result using extract()

Comment: but your question is ...? you want to follow these links and CrawlSpider does not? Please provide a sample web page link that has this content

Comment: this is the link http://www.kennedyhealth.org/careers.html
and now everytime I click a job for example: registered nurse, the url is not changing and still remains as the above link. I looked at the element and showed as <a class="bannertext" href="?fuseaction=search.jobDetails&template=dsp_job_details.cfm&cJobId=389139"> Registered Nurse - HHC </a>

Comment: now I get! The generated table comes from https://www.healthcaresource.com/kennedy/index.cfm?fuseaction=search.categoryList&template=dsp_job_categories.cfm which is a different domain. And now the problem is that I can not get to crawl it.